# Time between multiple times for restaurant breakfast,lunch,dinner

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate if the current time is within the opening hours of a restaurant.

This is online ordering system. So users needs to select the delivery time. The restaurant has the following opening and closing times:

```
Monday   11am-2:30pm   5:30pm-10pm
CLOSED TUESDAYS
Wednesday  11am-2:30pm   5:30pm-10pm
Thursday  11am-2:30pm   5:30pm-10pm
Friday  11am-2:30pm   5:30pm-12am
Saturday  11:30am-3pm   5:30pm-12am
Sunday  11:30am-3pm   5:30pm-10pm
```

I have to show a select box to select the delivery time within this time range.

I am using this script for single time. How can i use for multiple opening timings?

```
$start = new DateTime(); 
$start->setTime($start->format('H'), ceil($start->format('i') / 45) * 45);
$end = new DateTime('22:00:00');
$i=1;
while ($start <= $end) {
    if($i==1){
        echo '<option>' . $start->format('g:i a') . '</option>', "\n";
    }else{
        echo '<option>' . $start->format('g:i a') . '</option>', "\n";
    }
    $start->modify('+30 minute');
 $i++;
}
```

Comment: Create an' array with the days you are open, loop the code you have now in a foreach loop that goes through the days array.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: For all things DateTime, I would recommend using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) because that greatly simplifies time related calculations.

Answer (score 0):

By using an multidimentional array, you could easily add the time frame your need:

```
$open = array(
    "Monday" => array(
        0 => array(
            "begin" =>  "11:00 am",
            "end" =>    "02:30 pm"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "begin" =>  "05:30 pm",
            "end" =>    "10:00 pm"
        )
    ),

    "Wednesday" => array(
        0 => array(
            "begin" =>  "11:00 am",
            "end" =>    "02:30 pm"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "begin" =>  "05:30 pm",
            "end" =>    "10:00 pm"
        )
    ),  

    "Thursday" => array(
        0 => array(
            "begin" =>  "11:00 am",
            "end" =>    "02:30 pm"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "begin" =>  "05:30 pm",
            "end" =>    "10:00 pm"
        )
    ),

    "Friday" => array(
        0 => array(
            "begin" =>  "11:00 am",
            "end" =>    "02:30 pm"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "begin" =>  "05:30 pm",
            "end" =>    "12:00 am + 1day"
        )
    ),

    "Saturday" => array(
        0 => array(
            "begin" =>  "11:00 am",
            "end" =>    "03:00 pm"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "begin" =>  "05:30 pm",
            "end" =>    "12:00 am + 1day"
        )
    ),

    "Sunday" => array(
        0 => array(
            "begin" =>  "11:00 am",
            "end" =>    "03:00 pm"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "begin" =>  "05:30 pm",
            "end" =>    "10:00 pm"
        )
    )
);
```

And with a loop you can iterate through it and generate your 30 minutes delivery time.

```
foreach($open as $day => $hours)
{
    echo $day . "<br>";

    for($j = 0; $j < count($hours); $j++)
    {
        $start = new DateTime($hours[$j]['begin']); 
        $end = new DateTime($hours[$j]['end']);
        echo "<br>";
        $i=1;
        while ($start <= $end) {
            if($i==1){
                echo '<option>' . $start->format('g:i a') . '</option>', "\n";
            }else{
                echo '<option>' . $start->format('g:i a') . '</option>', "\n";
            }
            $start->modify('+30 minute');
         $i++;
        }
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

The result for this will be:

**Monday**

11:00 am
11:30 am
12:00 pm
12:30 pm
1:00 pm
1:30 pm
2:00 pm
2:30 pm

5:30 pm
6:00 pm
6:30 pm
7:00 pm
7:30 pm
8:00 pm
8:30 pm
9:00 pm
9:30 pm
10:00 pm

**Wednesday**

11:00 am
11:30 am
12:00 pm
12:30 pm
1:00 pm
1:30 pm
2:00 pm
2:30 pm

5:30 pm
6:00 pm
6:30 pm
7:00 pm
7:30 pm
8:00 pm
8:30 pm
9:00 pm
9:30 pm
10:00 pm

**Thursday**

11:00 am
11:30 am
12:00 pm
12:30 pm
1:00 pm
1:30 pm
2:00 pm
2:30 pm

5:30 pm
6:00 pm
6:30 pm
7:00 pm
7:30 pm
8:00 pm
8:30 pm
9:00 pm
9:30 pm
10:00 pm

**Friday**

11:00 am
11:30 am
12:00 pm
12:30 pm
1:00 pm
1:30 pm
2:00 pm
2:30 pm

5:30 pm
6:00 pm
6:30 pm
7:00 pm
7:30 pm
8:00 pm
8:30 pm
9:00 pm
9:30 pm
10:00 pm
10:30 pm
11:00 pm
11:30 pm
12:00 am

**Saturday**

11:00 am
11:30 am
12:00 pm
12:30 pm
1:00 pm
1:30 pm
2:00 pm
2:30 pm
3:00 pm

5:30 pm
6:00 pm
6:30 pm
7:00 pm
7:30 pm
8:00 pm
8:30 pm
9:00 pm
9:30 pm
10:00 pm
10:30 pm
11:00 pm
11:30 pm
12:00 am

**Sunday**

11:00 am
11:30 am
12:00 pm
12:30 pm
1:00 pm
1:30 pm
2:00 pm
2:30 pm
3:00 pm

5:30 pm
6:00 pm
6:30 pm
7:00 pm
7:30 pm
8:00 pm
8:30 pm
9:00 pm
9:30 pm
10:00 pm